# GMAIL App: Fetching already deleted email repeatedly

Tags: applications, sync, gmail

As we can configure other Email Account like YAHOO email in a GMAIL App, I added my YAHOO Email Account to GMAIL App and can now Access YAHOO Emails using GMAIL App.

**But the Issue is, when I delete my YAHOO Emails, somehow, it is again SYNC Back and I have to delete it again!**

This is happening repeatedly and I am simply not able to delete my YAHOO Emails from within GMAIL App.

I can delete YAHOO Email from yahoo.com (WEB Interface) and then they don't re-appear in GMAIL App.

I can delete GMAIL Emails, and they don't sync back, it is an issue only with YAHOO emails.

Android device: Micromax canvas 4
Android OS Version: Jelly Bean 4.2